# Unable to get Url from Jclouds BlobStore , S3Client

Tags: java, blobstore, jclouds

After storing the blob in the blobStore, it returns the Etag. But i want the URL to access the inputStream, just like amazonS3Client.getUrl(bucketName, key);
Here i dont want to use AmazonS3Client but use Jcloud S3 client or BlobStore.
Has anybody done this?
or in Scality , how do i get the URL of the object store?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways depending on whether you have a public access blob or want to grant temporary access to a private access blob.  For the former:

```
URI publicUri = blobStoreContext.getBlobStore().blobMetadata(bucketName, key).getPublicUri();
```

For the latter:

```
URI privateUri = blobStoreContext.getSigner().signGetBlob(bucketName, key).getEndpoint();
```

The latter vends a time-limited URI that authenticates via HTTP query parameters.